# Selenium does not click on a button, even when javascript is used

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried clicking on a button using normal selenium `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/app-game/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/app-bet-controls/div/app-bet-control[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button").click()`
but it did not perform any action, it simply moved to execute the other lines. no exceptions.

I then tried using javascript on selenium:

```
 bet = driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[12];")

driver.execute_script("return argument[0].click;", bet)
```

but still nothing happens, is there a way around this?
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMZXI.png)

Comment: am I understanding ur code correctly, that you want to save a variable returned by the click?

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML code and xpath that you've tried.

Comment: @Schulze yes, but its actually not necessary, I was just trying to get the button clicked

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. We tend to like a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until your button is displayed, you are clicking too soon...

Comment: I do have 10 second explicit wait before the command. this button is located in an iFrame, other elements can be clicked in this iframe but other buttons cannot be clicked,

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-success bet font-family-title ng-star-inserted']");
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-success bet font-family-title ng-star-inserted']"));
element.click()